# How does MySQL's ORDER BY RAND() work?

Tags: mysql, select, random

I've been doing some research and testing on how to do fast random selection in MySQL. In the process I've faced some unexpected results and now I am not fully sure I know how ORDER BY RAND() really works.

I always thought that when you do ORDER BY RAND() on the table, MySQL adds a new column to the table which is filled with random values, then it sorts data by that column and then e.g. you take the above value which got there randomly. I've done lots of googling and testing and finally found that the query [Jay offers in his blog](http://wanderr.com/jay/order-by-slow/2008/01/30/) is indeed the fastest solution:

```
SELECT * FROM Table T JOIN (SELECT CEIL(MAX(ID)*RAND()) AS ID FROM Table) AS x ON T.ID >= x.ID LIMIT 1;
```

While common ORDER BY RAND() takes 30-40 seconds on my test table, his query does the work in 0.1 seconds. He explains how this functions in the blog so I'll just skip this and finally move to the odd thing.

My table is a common table with a PRIMARY KEY `id` and other non-indexed stuff like `username`, `age`, etc. Here's the thing I am struggling to explain

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1; /*30-40 seconds*/
SELECT id FROM table ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1; /*0.25 seconds*/
SELECT id, username FROM table ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1; /*90 seconds*/
```

I was sort of expecting to see approximately the same time for all three queries since I am always sorting on a single column. But for some reason this didn't happen. Please let me know if you any ideas about this. I have a project where I need to do fast ORDER BY RAND() and personally I would prefer to use

```
SELECT id FROM table ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1;
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id=ID_FROM_PREVIOUS_QUERY LIMIT 1;
```

which, yes, is slower than Jay's method, however it is smaller and easier to understand. My queries are rather big ones with several JOINs and with WHERE clause and while Jay's method still works, the query grows really big and complex because I need to use all the JOINs and WHERE in the JOINed (called x in his query) sub request.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: As part of your research, you might also consider adding a random number column to your table instead of ordering by rand().  Then you could randomly pick rows by selecting the first row greater than a random number.

Comment: @MichaelPetito this will not work because you may want different a random "set" of random rows in each query while your solution will give the same "set" of random row.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

While there's no such thing as a "fast order by rand()", there is a workaround for your specific task.

**For getting any single random row**, you can do like this german blogger does: http://web.archive.org/web/20200211210404/http://www.roberthartung.de/mysql-order-by-rand-a-case-study-of-alternatives/ (I couldn't see a hotlink url. If anyone sees one, feel free to edit the link.)

The text is in german, but the SQL code is a bit down the page and in big white boxes, so it's not hard to see.

Basically what he does is make a procedure that does the job of getting a valid row. That generates a random number between 0 and max_id, try fetching a row, and if it doesn't exist, keep going until you hit one that does. He allows for fetching x number of random rows by storing them in a temp table, so you can probably rewrite the procedure to be a bit faster fetching only one row.

The downside of this is that if you delete A LOT of rows, and there are huge gaps, the chances are big that it will miss tons of times, making it ineffective.

**Update: Different execution times**

> SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1; /*30-40 seconds*/
>
> SELECT id FROM table ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1; /*0.25 seconds*/
>
> SELECT id, username FROM table ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1; /*90 seconds*/
>
> I was sort of expecting to see approximately the same time for all three queries since I am always sorting on a single column. But for some reason this didn't happen. Please let me know if you any ideas about this.

It may have to do with indexing. `id` is indexed and quick to access, whereas adding `username` to the result, means it needs to read that from each row and put it in the memory table. With the `*` it also has to read everything into memory, but it doesn't need to jump around the data file, meaning there's no time lost seeking.

This makes a difference only if there are variable length columns (varchar/text), which means it has to check the length, then skip that length, as opposed to just skipping a set length (or 0) between each row.

Comment: Basically that Jay's query I posted above is pretty much the same (if I understand it correctly of course) but is done completely in MySQL. So if I am not mistaken, the german blogger manually does just the same in PHP code.
Unfortunately I do delete from my table so it will definitely have gaps. I think the gaps won't be large but this is something I can't fully control so I can't use that method.

Comment: no he does it as a mysql procedure. which means that you don't have to duplicate it for every query. and if it's a table like a "posts" table in a forum, then it's fine. deletes will happen fairly often, but not often enough to pose a problem.

Comment: I see, thanks, I'll look into the solution that guy offers. But well, anyway I wonder why is ORDER BY RAND() fast when I select only `id`, very slow when I select `id` with `username` and slow when I select all columns? Why does the time vary so much depending on what columns I choose to select?

Comment: It may have to do with indexing. `id` is indexed and quick to access, whereas adding `username` to the result, means it needs to read that from each row and put it in the memory table. With the `*` it also has to read everything into memory, but it doesn't need to jump around the data file, meaning there's no time lost seeking. This makes a difference only if there are variable length columns, which means it has to check the length, then skip that length, as opposed to just skipping a set length (or 0) between each row.

Answer (score 2):

> It may have to do with indexing. id is
>   indexed and quick to access, whereas
>   adding username to the result, means
>   it needs to read that from each row
>   and put it in the memory table. With
>   the * it also has to read everything
>   into memory, but it doesn't need to
>   jump around the data file, meaning
>   there's no time lost seeking. This
>   makes a difference only if there are
>   variable length columns, which means
>   it has to check the length, then skip
>   that length, as opposed to just
>   skipping a set length (or 0) between
>   each row

Practice is better that all theories! Why not just to check plans? :)

```
mysql> explain select name from avatar order by RAND() limit 1;
+----+-------------+--------+-------+---------------+-----------------+---------+------+-------+----------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table  | type  | possible_keys | key             | key_len | ref  | rows  | Extra                                        |
+----+-------------+--------+-------+---------------+-----------------+---------+------+-------+----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | avatar | index | NULL          | IDX_AVATAR_NAME | 302     | NULL | 30062 | Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort |
+----+-------------+--------+-------+---------------+-----------------+---------+------+-------+----------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> explain select * from avatar order by RAND() limit 1;
+----+-------------+--------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+-------+---------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table  | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows  | Extra                           |
+----+-------------+--------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+-------+---------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | avatar | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 30062 | Using temporary; Using filesort |
+----+-------------+--------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+-------+---------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

 mysql> explain select name, experience from avatar order by RAND() limit 1;
+----+-------------+--------+------+--------------+------+---------+------+-------+---------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table  | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows  | Extra                           |
+----+-------------+--------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+-------+---------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | avatar | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 30064 | Using temporary; Using filesort |
+----+-------------+--------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+-------+---------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

I can tell you why the `SELECT id FROM ...` is much slower than the other two, but I am not sure, why `SELECT id, username` is 2-3 times faster than `SELECT *`.

When you have an index (the primary key in your case) and the result includes only the columns from the index, MySQL optimizer is able to use the data from the index only, does not even look into the table itself. The more expensive is each row, the more effect you will observe, since you substitute the filesystem IO operations with pure in-memory operations. If you will have an additional index on (id, username), you will have a similar performance in the third case as well.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you add an index `id, username` on the table see if that forces mysql to use the index rather than just a filesort and temp table.

Answer (score 0):

PrimaryKey's are indexed.  So those are "found" faster.

If you want a random (entire row) but the speed of using the PrimaryKey with the Random function..you can try this (below code):

You use the derived-table to "find" the primary-key of a single random row.  Then you join on it..to get the entire-row.

```
   Select * from my_thing mainTable
   JOIN
   (
      Select my_thing_key from my_thing order by RAND() LIMIT 1
    ) derived1
    on mainTable.my_thing_key = derived1.my_thing_key;
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `RAND()` is slower. And `*` is slower, too.

What I cannot explain is why `id, username` is slower than `*`.

This is a strange phenomenon that I cannot replicate.

The fastest method would be to get `MAX(id)` and store it in memory. Then, using your software pull a random number with it as the ceiling and then in SQL

```
SELECT id, username FROM table WHERE id > ? LIMIT 1;
```

and if no row, fall back to

```
SELECT id, username FROM table LIMIT 1;
```

If your MySQL installation is not buggy, you should do

```
SELECT id, username FROM table ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1;
```

with a small-medium data set. Doing two selects cannot be faster. But software is buggy.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a lightning fast solution: ​I came up with the following, I use this:

```sql
-- assign a random value to each row
SELECT id, RAND() AS random_order FROM my_table;

-- sort by the plus column and limit to the required number of rows (id)
SELECT rnd.id FROM (
    SELECT id, RAND() AS random_order FROM my_table 
) AS rnd ORDER BY rnd.random_order LIMIT 9;

-- the randomly selected ID list JOIN to yourself and query the necessary data
SELECT * FROM my_table AS myt
JOIN (
    SELECT rnd.id FROM (
        SELECT id, RAND() AS random_order FROM my_table 
    ) AS rnd ORDER BY rnd.random_order LIMIT 9
) AS random_list ON random_list.id = myt.id;

-- simplified, but also fast
SELECT * FROM my_table AS myt
JOIN (
    SELECT id FROM my_table ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 9
) AS random_list ON random_list.id = myt.id;
```

I ran some of my queries on live data tables:

```
Test table 1:    321 149 records, time:  0.2512 seconds
Test table 2:    865 706 records, time:  0.3070 seconds
Test table 3: 10 630 486 records, time: 52.1207 seconds
```

More information (hungarian): https://dev.to/benjaminhu/villamgyors-mysql-order-by-rand-lekerdezes-9pj