# Fastest way get random record from DB

Tags: database, mysql

I've been using order by rand() and it's becoming too much of a bottle neck.

I've tried this

```
SELECT id
FROM users
JOIN (
  SELECT CEIL( RAND( ) * ( SELECT MAX( id ) FROM users ) ) AS id
) AS r2
  USING ( id )
```

And it would work if all the id's were incremented, however with this particular table, they're not. The id's are fairly random themselves.

Anyone have a better method?  Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to request a random row in SQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19412/how-to-request-a-random-row-in-sql)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe create another table and put there all id's in compact way, adding id int autoincrement? If you using this function often, new table will pay for itself.

Comment: That's not a bad idea actually, so then I can use the improved query I posted but do it based off the autoincrement column - Good idea! Will try that.

Comment: Don't forget to add trigger to update compact table when original table is updated.

Answer (score 1):

Raveren: should be faster...

```
$ids = mysql::getSingleColumn('query');

$limit = 3;
shuffle($ids);

for($i=0;$<$limit;$i++)
  $usedIds[] = $ids[$i];

$idClause = implode(',',$usedIds);
```

Answer (score 0):

well if you have a lot of rows order by rand() is strongly NOT recommended because each row needs to have the random number calculated before the resultset can be ordered.

Maybe have a look at this -> http://www.electrictoolbox.com/msyql-alternative-order-by-rand/

Answer (score 0):

This is code I use for a quite performance-critical place in our application and it's benchmarked to perform way faster than `order by rand()`:

```
$ids = mysql::getSingleColumn("select id from table where simple_where_clause = 'value'");

$limit = 3;

for ($i = 0;$i<$limit;$i++) {
    $r = rand( 0, count( $ids ) );
    if (isset($ids[$r])) {
        $usedIds[] = $ids[$r];
        unset($ids[$r]);
    } else {
        $i--;
    }
}
$idClause = implode(',',$usedIds);
```

I then use the $idClause in the main query: `[...] WHERE id in ({$idClause})`

Answer (score -1):

You can use this (it has some downsides)

```
SELECT id FROM users ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0,1
```

[Mysql reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_rand)

Comment: Wasn't that exactly what Dave tries to avoid for performance reasons?

Comment: also watch this post 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2663710/how-does-mysqls-order-by-rand-work