# What happens when ORDER BY is given a number?

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I just started learning MySQL, and the book I'm reading has the following example:

```
SELECT last_name, first_name, birth FROM president
ORDER BY IF(birth IS NULL,0,1), birth DESC;
```

What I wish to know is how those numbers (0 and 1) affect the behavior of `ORDER BY`--when you give `ORDER BY` a number, what does it do with it?

A hint I found is that random ordering is done the following way:

```
SELECT * from TABLE ORDER BY rand();
```

But I still don't know why it works.

Comment: Personally, I'd prefer the ASCENDING death over the DESCENDING death. I hear it's kind of hot down there. *whistles*

Comment: It sorts by that number? I don't see where you are getting confused by that.

Comment: JohnFX, the documentation (and the book) say ORDER BY takes two arguments, DESC and ASC. Not explanation of this other syntax (ORDER BY being given numbers) is given. This is why I'm confused.

Comment: glowcoder, changed it to birth so it sounds less morbid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It orders the data so that the rows where `IF(birth IS NULL, 0, 1)` returns 0 appear before the rows where it returns 1.

You might care to notice that this is quite different from what happens if you write:

```
ORDER BY 1;
```

In this case, it orders by the first column in the result list.  This is obsolescent syntax, but still required by the SQL standard.

Comment: I see, so it acts as a user-defined sorting mechanism, separate from DESC and ASC. Am I correct?

Comment: @Ikram: Not a separate mechanism - it just means that (since you omitted DESC) that the data in the first ORDER BY column is ordered in ascending order, zeroes before ones, just like any other column would be; then, within a group (0 or 1), the second value (death) controls the order of the tied rows in descending order.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Still not sure if I'm getting it right though. Is there anywhere that I can read the technical details of how ORDER BY works?

Comment: @Jonathan I found [another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2663710/how-does-mysqls-order-by-rand-work) where the asker says: "I always thought that when you do ORDER BY RAND() on the table, MySQL adds a new column to the table which is filled with random values, then it sorts data by that column." This makes sense to me, but I don't know if it is correct.

Comment: @Ikram: it is correct.  You can read about ORDER BY at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select.html.

Comment: @Jonathan. Thank you for all the answers. The link didn't help since it doesn't explain what happens when ORDER BY is given a number through IF or RAND. I think I've understood this stuff by now, but out of curiosity, why does it make a difference when ORDER BY is given a number explicitly rather than through RAND or IF? As a programmer I'm used to treating a function that returns a number (such as RAND) like it _is_ a literal number, so to me it shouldn't have made a difference whether a 1 or 0 was returned by a function or given to ORDER BY manually.

Comment: @Ikram: if the number is a literal (`ORDER BY 1, 2`) then it is referring to columns by ordinal position (1st selected, 2nd...). Otherwise (e.g. `ORDER BY colname`) it is an expression that is a column in the select-list, or (as in the case of `ORDER BY IF(...)` or `ORDER BY rand()`) some expression that is evaluated (once) for each row and then used as the appropriate term in the sort order. It seemed to me that the reference says that; maybe I've had too many years experience reading manuals worse than the MySQL manuals, or I'm dragging too much background knowledge into the interpretation.