# Displaying Data Randomly in PHP From Database

Tags: php, mysql

I'm Building a Simple PHP Page for MCQS (Multiple Choice Questions). I'm Using MySQL Database to retrieve data. I want to **Display Options / Alternatives** *( i.e: field_correct_answer_value, field_wrong_answer_1_value, field_wrong_answer_2_value, field_wrong_answer_3_value, field_wrong_answer_4_value)* in **Random Order** with stylesheet so i can identify which one is correct.

```
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<hr><div id=q1>". $row["field_question_value"]."</div>";
        echo "<div id=a1>". $row["field_correct_answer_value"]."</div>";
        echo "<div id=a2>". $row["field_wrong_answer_1_value"]."</div>";
        echo "<div id=a2>". $row["field_wrong_answer_2_value"]."</div>";
        echo "<div id=a2>". $row["field_wrong_answer_3_value"]."</div>";
        echo "<div id=a2>". $row["field_wrong_answer_4_value"]."</div>";
    }
```

Is it Possible?

Comment: You may be better of using MySQL's ability to randomise the results with [ORDER BY RAND()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2663710/how-does-mysqls-order-by-rand-work).  Also ideally nothing in the web source should indicate which is the correct answer as this means people can cheat.

Comment: ORDER BY RAND() also randomize the question position. I don't want to hide the source cause its a simple page that display mcqs with answers. Similar to this one: http://fgstudy.com/mcqs/general-knowledge-mcqs-for-css-and-others-set-2/

Answer (score 0):

```
($result->num_rows > 0) {
// output data of each row
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
//FOR RANDOMIZATION OPTION COLLECTING DATA IN ARRAY AND SHUFFLING THEM
$corr = "<div id=a1>" . $row["field_correct_answer_value"] . "</div>";
$wor1 = "<div id=a2>" . $row["field_wrong_answer_1_value"] . "</div>";
$wor2 = "<div id=a2>" . $row["field_wrong_answer_2_value"] . "</div>";
$wor3 = "<div id=a2>" . $row["field_wrong_answer_3_value"] . "</div>";
$wor4 = "<div id=a2>" . $row["field_wrong_answer_4_value"] . "</div>";
$opt = array($corr, $wor1, $wor2, $wor3, $wor4,);
$opt_ran = shuffle($opt);

echo "<hr><div id=q1>". $row["field_question_value"]."</div>";
//FOR DISPLAYING RANDOM OPTIONS
foreach ($opt as $number) {
echo $number;
}
}
```