# Insert random Concate Select Query

Tags: mysql, sql, string, sum, sql-insert

I am trying to get random rows, with only 4 out of 9 columns, concate the different rows, and insert them into the table

So for example:

```
test    1   9
test2   2   5 
test3   3   6
```

I want to randomly select 2 out of the 3 rows
concate the test2 and test3 to test2, test3
and insert "test2, test3" 2+3(5) 5+6(11)
into 3 different columns.

Is this at all possible and to what extend?
Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I follow you correctly, you can randomly select two rows in a subquery, then aggregate in the outer query.

Assuming that the columns of your table are `tid`, `val_1` and `val_2`:

```
select group_concat(tid) col_1, sum(val_1) val1, sum(val_2) val_2 
from (select * from mytable order by rand() limit 2) t
```

You can easily turn this to an `insert` statement:

```
insert into mytable (tid, val_1, val_2)
select ... -- the above query
```

Comment: This is insane! I was worried my question might me too confuse to understand but you did it! as far as i can tell its working! Sadly i do not completly understand whats going on, but i hope ill learn that at some point (for example, why is there a random "t" at the end)
Thanks again, you are awesome!

Comment: @Leno22ß6, as you need random rows out that's why you see `rand()` function. So the inner sub query orders the rows randomly and then limit the result to `2`. A good SO link for `rand()` function https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2663710/how-does-mysqls-order-by-rand-work...... Second point that each sub query you create in a select statement should have a specific alias assigned to it and that's why you see `t` at the end.

Comment: Thank you very much, ive actually seen the order by rand() trick before, one of my biggest confusions now is, why the sums have their ID's written twice, once in the () and once outside, is it just the "AS [name]" but without the AS?